# Log events in a html text box gradually

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a web page with a text area (or text editor) and I want to show some log messages in the box which the log messages are added gradually. Consider when we install an application it shows logs about what is going on incrementally.

I already have a page with an editor (ace editor) which shows data but I have some problems:

1. When data is added to the editor content, all the box is refreshed.
2. Besides refreshing, the cursor appears at the start of the box instead of placing at the end.

Please help me to find the write component for logging events in the web page. Thank you.

Html side code:

```
<button
      data-toggle="modal" href="#edit_file_content_modal"
      ng-click="process(migrateResult)"
      class="btn btn-icon-only red"
      uib-popover="Log">

      <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit_file_content_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit_file_content_modal">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="edit_file_content_modal-title">File Content</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div>
                <code-editor
                        code-model="content"
                        header-title="header">
                </code-editor>
            </div>



            <div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="saveFile()" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled=false>
                        Save
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancelCallback()">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the js file, I listen on an event and add the received data to the editor content and apply the changes:

```
io.socket.on(obj.migrateSourceOwner.sourceFile, function (data) {
    $scope.content += ("\n" + data);
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Leopard: some parts of code is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is plain js sample to update a textarea hope it may usefull

```js
var txt = document.getElementById('log');

setInterval(function(){
txt.value += '\ntest';
},2000);
```

```html
<textarea id='log' rows=50 cols=60 autofocus>


</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems it solves my first problem, but when I run the code snippet it didn't show the latest message. I mean it doesn't auto-scroll to the latest message.

Comment: you have to focus your textbox or directive after updating the value

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: if you using use `focus()` method on element if you using textbox just set autofocus property